# I define my springboot api by Swagger, and how can I use it in other modules to implement the controller?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, swagger, swagger-ui, java

The following is the screenshot of my project structure. The spring-boot-stub module is the api, and I want to use it in module server which is a spring boot application.

[image]

The api is generated by Swagger, and one of the api is as follows:

**ProductsApi.class:**

```html
import io.swagger.annotations.Api;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiOperation;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.annotations.ApiResponses;
import io.wondergate.polaris.model.Product;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Api(
    value = "products",
    description = "the products API"
)
public interface ProductsApi {
    @ApiOperation(
        value = "",
        notes = "Get the list of products",
        response = Product.class,
        responseContainer = "List",
        tags = {}
    )
    @ApiResponses({        @ApiResponse(
            code = 200,
            message = "OK",
            response = Product.class
        )})
    @RequestMapping(
        value = {"/products"},
        produces = {"application/json"},
        consumes = {"application/json"},
        method = {RequestMethod.GET}
    )
    ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getProducts();
}
```

I implement the api in module server as follows:

```html
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import io.wondergate.polaris.api.ProductsApi;
import io.wondergate.polaris.model.Product;
import io.wondergate.polaris.server.dao.ProductDao;
import io.wondergate.polaris.server.dao.ResourceInfoDao;
import io.wondergate.polaris.server.model.ResourceInfo;
import io.wondergate.polaris.server.model.ServerProduct;
import io.wondergate.polaris.server.utils.Convertor;

@Controller
public class ProductController implements ProductsApi {

    @Autowired
    private ProductDao productDao;
    @Autowired
    private ResourceInfoDao resourceInfoDao;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    public String index() {
        return "Greetings from Spring Boot!";
    }

//    @RequestMapping("/products")
    public ResponseEntity<List<Product>> getProducts() {
        List<Product> productList = new ArrayList<Product>();
        Iterable<ServerProduct> allProducts = productDao.findAll();
        for (ServerProduct serverProduct : allProducts) {
            Iterable<ResourceInfo> resourceInfo = resourceInfoDao.findByProductId(serverProduct.getId());
            Product product = Convertor.serverProductToProduct(serverProduct, resourceInfo);
            productList.add(product);
        }
        ResponseEntity<List<Product>> res = new ResponseEntity<List<Product>>(productList, HttpStatus.OK);
        return res;
    }

}
```

However, though the project can be compiled and launched successfully, it cannot map the url routes as I wish, e.g.

[image]

So how can I do it? I want to make the api define module and implement module separate, so that when I modify the api definition, I needn't modify its implementation(e.g., url route).

Comment: `@RequestMapping` is read by spring during context creation on the concrete class, so strictly speaking it is not aware of its interface. A dirty workaround would be adding it to the impl (like you commented out) and reference the value(s) to a static field on the interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel sorry for this question. Actually the project can map the url routes in the right way. The true cause of the above problem is the mismatching of content type.